# Microsoft Access: Import CSV file from a list of multiple files

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a huge file around 10 GB in *.csv format. It is data from 1960 to present date for different regions. I was able to break down the file by the regions. There are about 8000 regions and I split the file by regions so I have 8000 files about 2 MB each.

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to create a Access database system to look up data for each region. Is it by:

1. Separating the file into small files (i.e by each region 8000 files) by region name and importing them to access each time, OR
2. Splitting them into constant sizes about 1 GB each and querying them.

In either case, how do I import the files to Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may be aware, an Access database file is limited to 2GB in size, so you almost certainly won't be able to keep all of the information in one file. Even if it did just barely fit, keeping that much information in a single Access database file would likely be rather slow to work with.

Depending on the "shape" of your data there may be other limits in Access that could cause difficulties in your particular situation. For example, a table (or query) is limited to 255 columns. If you haven't done so already, take a look at the [Access specifications](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/access-2010-specifications-HA010341462.aspx) before proceeding too much further with this.

And in any case, consider using another database as the back-end. Your data may even be too large for single database in SQL Server Express Edition (maximum of 10GB total size per database, as I recall), but even if you had to split the data into two SQL Express databases it would be easier to deal with than a dozen (or more?) Access databases.

Bear in mind that if you use a different database back-end you may still be able to use Access as a query and reporting tool (via ODBC linked tables).

### Edit re: comment

Based on your description, if you will **never** need to query across regions (and remember that **"never" is a *very* long time™**) then your 8000-file approach would be feasible. However, I wouldn't necessarily recommend importing the corresponding CSV data every time you want to run a query. Instead, I would borrow ideas from both Tom's and HansUp's answers:

**Plan "A":** Start by running queries directly against the CSV files themselves to see if that is fast enough for your needs. You could test that by creating a [linked table](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx) to the CSV file and running some typical queries. As Tom mentioned, a CSV linked table cannot be indexed, so if you find that the queries are too slow then you may have to go to Plan "B".

**Plan "B":** If you do need to import the CSV data then you'll probably want to use HansUp's suggestion of using `DoCmd.TransferText` to help automate the process. It seems wasteful to import the specific CSV file for every query, so you might consider creating ~8000 `.accdb` files and then using a query like...

```
strSQL = _
        "SELECT * FROM TableName " & _
        "IN ""C:\__tmp\region12345.accdb"" " & _
        "WHERE StartDate BETWEEN #2013-05-10# AND #2013-05-15#"
```

...where your code could substitute

- the name of the appropriate `.accdb` file based on the region of interest, and
- the required date range.

Comment: Gord Thank you for the reply. Due to lack of resources/ restrictions for user I am compelled to use access for this purpose. So as a solution I was modelling it so that access can use 8000 smaller files of size 2 MB each an dload each file when needed. I do not need to handle cross regional queries and all I need is to get the regional number, start and end date and return it to the user. So is Access too slow to do this Thanks

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest any other database systems I can use on Mac as I SQL express is not available for mac

Comment: @Agng I can't make any specific recommendations about Mac software, but it appears that both MySQL and PostgreSQL are available for Mac OS X. I am a bit puzzled, however: You say that you can't use SQL Server because it is "not available" for Mac, but Access is a Windows application so you can't use Access on a Mac either (not natively, anyway). How were you planning to use Access?

Answer (score 2):

If you will be doing this with VBA, you can use the [DoCmd.TransferText Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214141%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to import CSV data into Access.

I wouldn't want to do that in your situation, though.  10 GB is too much data to reasonably manage in Access.  And if you partition that into separate db files, querying data pulled from multiple db files is challenging and slow.  Furthermore, if the query's combined result set hits the 2 GB Access limit, you will get a confusing error about insufficient disk space.

This is not a reasonable job for data storage in MS Access.

Comment: Hi HansUp, Thanks for the reply. I know the file size is too large for Access to handle. The good news is I do not need to query multiple db at a time. All I it need to perform is that the user will enter region, start date and end date and the db has to find the file with the data which I have seperated into 8000 files. My only concern is if Acess can load one file at a time and if it is possible how do I do that. Is this method efficient or it takes too long to find and load the file. I know it is much difficult in Access that other dbs but thats the challenge due to limited res of user

Comment: OK, it's much more reasonable if you will only be querying one db file at a time.  However in the case you described, perhaps you should segregate the data into db files based on date range instead of 8000 regions ... maybe one for each decade.  But however you split up the data, I think you will need to use VBA code to identify the target db file based on the user's search values ... and dynamically adjust your query SQL to match.

Answer (score 1):

@Gords & @HansUps are very good answers. Use a better backend for your data. Free ones would include SQL Express & MySQL. If you're in a corporate environment, then you may have a license for MS SQL Server.

However, if you insist on doing this doing this in strictly Access, here are two related ideas. Both ideas require that you link and de-link (using VBA) to the data you need as you need it.

---

You don't have to import a CSV file to be able to see it as a table. You can link to it just as you would a table in another database.

- Positives: You don't have to change your existing data format.
- Drawbacks: You can't edit your existing data, nor can you index it,
  so queries may be slow.

---

Or, you can convert each CSV file into it's own Access DB (you can do this with VBA to automate this). Then, like in the above suggestion, link & de-link the tables as needed.

- Positives: You can edit your existing data, and also index it,    so
  queries may be quick.
- Drawbacks: It's an awful amount of work just to avoid using a
  different backend DB.